# How to format data into a python list

Tags: python, text-processing

I am trying to figure out how to take data which looks like:

```
1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 10

11 12 13 14 15

16 17 18 19 20
```

from a file and make it look like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,

6, 7, 8, 9, 10,

11, 12, 13, 14, 15,

16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Each line represents a row from the data file, so the starting format should not be confused with:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7...
```

The original data is contained in a file so it must be first read in and then rewritten with the commas and brackets into a new file. My starting point would be to first read in the data:

`with open("data.txt","r") as data:
    lines = data.readlines()`

Then I know that I have to take the read lines and rewrite them in the format I need but I don't know how to do this for each element of each line.

Comment: Sssh.. did you try _splitting_?

Comment: @devnull I would assume that's a hard "no" on their part

Comment: @RUJordan And a _no_ to searching for a solution too.

Comment: I just did and it worked! Thanks for the simple and effective answer!

Comment: The way I was wording my search wasn't brining up my answer, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell Python to split each line by its spaces, and then join the resulting elements with ', ' like this:

```
', '.join(line_in.split())
```

This will convert a string like:

```
'6 7 8 9 10'
```

in this:

```
'6, 7, 8, 9, 10'
```

Now, you need to decide whether this is the last line of the file or not. If it is the last line of the file you need to append a `"]"` whereas if it is not the last line, you need to add a `","`.

At the beginning of the file you need also to add a `"["`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
>>> data = open('data.txt').read().split()
>>> data = [int(item) for item in data if item.isdigit()
>>> data
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

This will get all of the integers in the file. If you don't care, just remove the second, line, and call `data = open('data.txt').read().split()`.